# How to get json object in ajax response using local .json file and jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Using jquery ajax request like this

```
$.ajax({
url: 'mydata.json',
type: 'get',
error: function(data){
},
success: function(data){
  data=jQuery.parseJSON(data);
  //do something with data              
    }
});
```

It is working perfect except when I implement it on server with a server url which internally generates json response object and return. then I don't need jQuery.parseJSON(data). Is there a way where I can use local json file and get response as json object?

Answer (score 3):

```
$.ajax({
url: 'mydata.json',
type: 'get',
dataType: 'json',
error: function(data){
},
success: function(data){
  //do something with data              
    }
});
```

Specifying `dataType: 'json'` tells jQuery to expect JSON data and automatically parse it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking to see if the returned data has already been converted to a JSON object. If so, then there's no reason to parse it.

```
    $.ajax({ 
      url: 'mydata.json', 
      type: 'get', 
      error: function(data){ }, 
      success: function(data){ 
        console.log(data); //check to see if jQuery has already converted the response to a JSON object
        //data=jQuery.parseJSON(data); //do something with data
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a know issue that `success()` callback won't fire on local jQuery.ajax. Use `complete()` instead if you intend to run the script locally. Also because of this issue, you should not use jQuery.getJSON for the job (because the function will only fire when success.)

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON('mydata.json').done(function(response) {
    console.log("Success");
}).fail(function() {
    console.log("Error");
});
```